# In C++ can I use a table of function pointers to jump (not call) a function?

Tags: c++

In C++ can I use a table of function pointers to jump (not call) a function? I know how to make and call a jump table, but I am building a scanner and want to jump between routines efficiently, so I want to do a jump so the same stack frame is used for the target routine. I will make the profiles the same.

Comment: If you must jump between two pieces of code in the same frame, why call them functions, in the first place?

Comment: If your functions are simple enough, let the compiler handle the optimization. It’s clever enough to omit the stack frames when applicable.

Comment: @DYZ: Function pointers are the only (portable) way of identifying code in C++.

Comment: @Macmade: Indirect calls (via function pointer) are usually enough to defeat that optimization.

Comment: To follow up on why I qualified my comment to DYZ with "(portable)": gcc has computed-goto and lets you take the address of labels, but this is both totally non-standard and also results in a single very big function.

Comment: It is not really clear what is your execution pattern. Are you trying to reduce the number of frame buffers in recursion or you are trying to speedup function calls at the same level of recursion?

Answer (score 8):

No you can't, but there is a well-known pattern to avoid accumulation of stack frames during repeated lookups: Continuation-Trampoline Style.

Instead of this:

```
void scanner1( ... )
{
     fn_table[next]();
}
```

do this:

```
int scanner2( ... )
{
     return next;
}

while ((next = fn_table[next]()) != END) {}
```

Because there's a return immediately preceding every call, the stack depth doesn't increase.

An additional benefit is that if you want to add tracing of the states visited, you can do so at a single point (inside the trampoline-processing loop) instead of scattered across all scanner functions.

It gets more complicated if there's state to pass to the next handler, but not by very much (use output params instead of return value, for example, or return a smart pointer to a functor object, e.g. `std::function<void()>` that has the arguments prebound).

This is also covered [in the wikipedia article on tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion#Through_trampolining).